# PowerApps: Zoom Image in HTML Text Control

Tags: css, powerapps

Is there a way to Zoom In an image when it's clicked or hovered in powerapps?

Here is the code in the HTML Text Control:

```
Concatenate(
"<b><font color=black>", currentWorkItemId, "</font></b>  ", LookUp(extendedWorkItemList, Id = currentWorkItemId, Title),
    "<br></br><br></br><br></br>",
    "<b>Test Case</b>",
    "<hr>",
    LookUp(workItemDetails, WorkItemId = Value(currentWorkItemId), TestCase)
)
```

Here is the generated HTML Text:

```
<b><font color=black>36066</font></b>Test<br></br><br></br><br></br><b>Test Case</b><hr><span style="display:inline !important;">Test Case<br><br><span style="display:inline !important;">This a just a Test :)<span>&nbsp;</span></span><a href="google.com" style="box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;">TestUrl</a><br style="box-sizing:border-box;"><span style="display:inline !important;"><br></span><br></span><img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200403151026/adblur_gfg.png" alt='Geeks Image'><br><br>
```

And here is how it looks like:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciaYA.png)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do did it by clicking on the original image.
Please read through this whole response before trying.

7.3 steps

**Step 1**

Original image is 'Html text' control called **'Image'** with HtmlText set to the following (including the quotes around in the string *remove the space after the first <*). :

"< img src="&ThisItem.Image&" width="&Self.Width&">"
(yours might be your whole html output since it in not just a single image but rather a whole html string)

*ThisItem.Image refers to the selected SPO List Item in the form refencing a column called 'Image'. That is a 'Hyperlink or Picture' column set to Hyperlink. You may not need this, since you are already getting the URL from a another type of column.*

**Step 2**
Set a variable on the OnScreen or App OnStart function to
Set(varImageLargeVisible, false)

**Step 3**
Set the original image OnSelect to
UpdateContext({varImageLargeVisible:true})
Make sure image DisplayMode is set to Edit

**Step 4**
Create a new HTML Text control. Set it to the size you want. If you want to block behind it off make the background color white or something to block out what is behind the control.

**Step 5**
Add an Icon, the X or something obvious so the user knows how to close the large image.
Set OnSelect to
UpdateContext({varImageLargeVisible:false})

**Step 6**
Change the Visible function for both the new Html Text control AND the icon to
If(varImageLargeVisible = true, true)

**Step 7**
Set the HtmlText to:

Substitute(Image.HtmlText, "width=443","width="&App.Width&"")

"width=443" is the width of the original control found on the right info panel.

7a-
Replace "Image" in 'Image.HtmlText' with the referenced image. (This references the original control called 'Image')

7b-
Replace the "443" in "width=443" with the width of your original control

7c-
Replace the "&App.Width&" in "width="&App.Width&" with the new size you want the image to be. If it will be a static size you can put in a number here instead of the dynamic size. "& &" breaks up the html within PowerApps so if you put in a static number, removed that as well.

**Notes**
I think you will need to define a width in your html output so the replace has something to replace.
<img src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200403151026/adblur_gfg.png" alt='Geeks Image' **width="0000"**> (replace the 0000 with the size your image currently is.)

Hope that makes sense.